# how to synchronize git-svn repositories

Tags: git, git-svn, rsync

I've been using git-svn for the past three weeks.

**Currently my work flow is like this.**

1. ssh into my development box,
2. create/edit/delete files there(git svn rebase, git checkout -b topic branch)
3. check whether the web app is working fine.
4. commit to svn.(git rebase master, git checkout master, git merge topic branch, git svn dcommit)

**Problems**

1. this workflow is very easy for quick edits on the dev box(ssh). But as the remote editing becomes slow overtime, it becomes difficult.
2. Note: I can't setup the exact copy of my web application in my local machine(since it pulls data from various sources, and lot of other configurations)

***What I want is to edit files locally , move the files to the server, test, commit.***

What could be a good workflow for this?

**My previous attempts include,**

1. edit files locally, scp files, test, dcommit
2. edit files locally, rsync with dev box, test, dcommit
3. edit files locally, git push to dev box, test, dcommit  (git pull from local box to dev box   is not possible because local box is behind a router)

I haven't tried the last step, since the git-svn mentions it is dangerous to push/pull/merge from another git repo if you are using git-svn.

Can you please suggest some efficient workflow with sample commands?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be missing something, but I think the warnings in the `git svn` documentation don't apply to the workflow I'm suggesting below.  (I'm assuming that you're happy to only `git svn dcommit` from the dev box, incidentally.)

1. Clone the repository from your dev box onto your local machine.  Suppose you then create a new topic branch locally called `excellent`.  You do some work on that new branch.
2. Now you want to test it on the dev box, but to avoid the problems with pushing into a non-bare repository you can use a technique [suggested in the git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#How_would_I_use_.22git_push.22_to_sync_out_of_a_host_that_I_cannot_pull_from.3F) where you push directly to a ref under `refs/remotes/`.  For example, you might do:

   ```
   git push origin excellent:refs/remotes/from-desktop/excellent
   ```
3. Now you should log in to the dev box.  You can then create a new branch based on the ref you just pushed with `git checkout -b excellent from-desktop/excellent`
4. You can work on this branch as you would on the topic branch in your example, and if you're happy with it, make sure that you still do the same sequence before doing a `git svn dcommit`, i.e. `git rebase master`, `git checkout master`, `git merge excellent`, `git svn dcommit`

I don't see why that workflow would create problems with `git svn`, since you're being careful to rebase your work and merge it into `master` before doing the `git svn dcommit`.

Comment: After I make changes in the third step, how can I make that changes to go into my local machine? A git pull from my local machine? ie) git pull origin excellent will be fine?

Comment: @someisaac: if you're trying to get your changes back after rebasing `excellent` on the dev box, you should probably use `git pull --rebase origin excellent`, instead otherwise there'll be a merge where you have the some of the same changes in the history of both parents.

Comment: I have one more doubt. After git pull --rebase origin excellent, and making some changes locally, how to make that changes go into dev box? I tried git push origin excellent:refs/remotes/from-desktop/excellent again, and it went, but how can i merge this changes into the excellent branch of the devbox repo. I tried git merge excellent from-desktop/excellent.But a merge commit is created thanks

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear that worked.  I'm afraid that if your end goal is to get your commits into svn, a lot of rebasing is basically inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

I use a workflow that is inverted from yours and it works well.

By inverted, I mean that my git-svn repo is on my local box, and I push to the dev box.

There are three repos:

1. The git-svn repo on the local box.
2. I create a bare repo on the dev box, then push from the git-svn repo into this one.
3. On the dev box, I clone the bare repo into a working directory that I use for testing. After the initial creation of the repo, I pull from the bare repo described in #2 above.

I rarely make edits in the testing repo (#3). If I do make a trivial edit, I will often just manually make the same edit on repo #1 on the local box. I have on occasion pushed commits from the testing repo (#3) back into the bare repo (#2), and then pulled them into the git-svn repo (#1) from the local box. More often what happens is that I'm hunting a hard-to-find bug and making a bunch of little changes directly in the test repo (#3), and when I find the bug I just throw all of those debugging changes away and fix the bug directly in the git-svn repo (#1), then push to #2, pull into #3 and test.

Workflow is:

1. [local] git co -b myfeature
2. [local] hack hack hack
3. [local] git commit -m'did stuff' -a
4. [local] git push devbox myfeature
5. [dev] cd myapp; git pull; git co origin/myfeature
6. [dev] test test test
7. Repeat 2-6
8. [local] git co master
9. [local] git svn rebase
10. [local] git co myfeature
11. [local] git rebase master
12. [local] git co master
13. [local] git merge --ff-only myfeature
14. [local] git svn dcommit
15. [local] git br -d myfeature

I will sometimes do an interactive rebase before step 8 to clean up the history.

Comment: "The dev box has a bare repo, and the workspace with the app checkout."   the workspace with the app checkout means, you clone your app from the bare repo?. can you please elaborate this?

Comment: what will you do when you have to edit in the devbox(quick edit), you commit and push it to the bare repo? and svn dcommit from your local box? what to do when i want one more local machine(like a laptop). Thanks.

Comment: @someisaac - Edited for clarity, let me know if you still have questions. Regarding the use of another local machine: beware the complexity that introducing another repo adds. Everything has to go back to svn and you want to maintain a nice linear history. You can either make a new git-svn repo on the laptop, or you can clone the repo #1 described in my answer. You'll have to figure out how synchronizing to the dev box works best for you in this case.

Comment: Thanks i'll try this and let you know if i have any questions.

Comment: Your work flow is interesting, and as far as i tried it worked well.But currently i'm using the method suggested by @Mark Longair.Thanks.